# SQL2012 client connection after failover

Tags: sql-server

After failover occurs in a SQL 2012 Availability group. the application is not able to make connection to the Listener when the DB is online on Secondary host. I have checked all the settings and they are same on primary and secondary. Really not possible to find what Am I missing.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried ping/telnet to make sure network access works?

Comment: In what language is the app written? Could you post the connection string that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

So you try to connect to read only secondary via AG listener. I would suggest you start to verify your read only routing configuration.

1. Use SSMS or sqlcmd to establish connection to secondary via AG listener. Like connect and query @@servername. If this step doesn't give you secondary result, you should double check your read only routing configuration rather than your application issue.
2. If above step gives you correct secondary, then you should check your application provide correct connection string, like ApplicationIntent, target DB name, etc.