# Connection to Availability Group Listener gives a 'Transport Level' Error in SSMS when I shut down Primary

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, sql-server-2019, alwayson

I have a Node1\INST1 SQL Server instance which is the Primary and a Node2\Inst2 which is the Secondary in the High Availability Group. Both shows 'Synchronized' as the status, and both show 'No Data Loss'. I have also configured the Failover correctly.

Both are up and I have my SSMS open with a connection to the Listener,1496. I fire a query against this one test table and it returns the correct results.

Next, I stop the SQL Service on the Primary (to test the Failover). The 'Automatic Failover' happens correctly and I can see now the Node2\Inst2 is Primary.

But my query on the listener connection window gives that typical:

> A transport level occurred

error if I fire that query again. Shouldn't that query work seamlessly? Like tomorrow, If I have a .NET app with the connection string pointing to the listener, what kind of issues will I face when the Primary goes down?

Please let me know If I am testing it wrong or if I need to do something else.

Thanks

Comment: What client tool are you using to query?  Did you open a new connection after failover?  Are Node1 and Node2 in the same subnet?

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft for your response. I am using SSMS (Management Studio) and tried to Reconnect to the listener. I was even unable to connect to the Listener at that point. Yes, I configured it to be in the same subnet. The Failover was not the issue. But connection to the Listener is, as tomorrow we are planning to build a .NET app with a connection string pointing to the Listener (and if the Primary goes down then)

Comment: I think I will try to look at this configuration. This is exactly the same issue I am worried about. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393691/sql2012-client-connection-after-failover?rq=1

Comment: Verify that the listener IP is online at the secondary, and test connectivity with test-netconnection.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft. Will try it out today.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I am still trying to figure out why this behavior. I am using Management Studio on both Node 1 and Node 2 to test this. When Node 1 is Primary, I can connect to the Listener from within Node 1. But cannot connect to the listener from the SSMS instance on Node 2. Similarly when the Failover happens and Node 2 now becomes the primary, I can ONLY connect to the Listener from within my SSMS instance on Node 2 and not Node1.  I fail to understand the reason behind this. Listener is on port 1496 and I have 1496 open on both Node1 and Node2.

Comment: Am I better off connecting to the Listener and testing it from outside of Node1/Node2 VMs?  There is nothing on the MS site covering this either. It just says connect to the listener.

Comment: Are these VMs in Azure?  If so that's the expected behavior as single-subnet listeners require an Azue Load Balancer.  And yes, generally you want to test from a machine outside the cluster.

Comment: These VMs are on my local laptop as this was more of a Proof Of Concept.  I just feel so stupid. YOUR previous comment of using test-netconnection helped me figure it out! It was the damn PORT! I had opened 5022 and 1433 and a bunch of UDP ports except the one I needed. Thanks a lot! Truly appreciate it. Works like a charm now.